# Share .currentMember across two different dimension ranges?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am working on an SSAS cube calc measure that uses two different date dimension ranges to filter a dataset from inception to a specific date (eg., NULL:[Date].CurrentMember).  In this specific example, each date range's .CurrentMember is always going to be set to the **same date value**.  I'd like to avoid having the users put two date fields on their pivots.

Suggestions?

I currently have this, and it works fine as long as the calc is fed with values for both Date1 and Date2:

```
WITH CALCULATED MEMBER [Measures].[Metric - Inception-to-Date]
 AS sum(
    (
        {
        (
        [Date1].[Date Value].[All]
        ,[Date2].[Date Value].&[1900-02-00]:[Date2].[Date Value].CurrentMember
         )
        ,(
        NULL:[Date1].[Date Value].CurrentMember
        ,[Date2].[Date Value].&[1900-01-01]
         )
    }
        ,[Measures].[Metric2] 
    ) 
    ,[Measures].[Metric1]
    )
```

What I'd like to do is somehow REUSE the value of Date2.CurrentMember for the range for Date1 so the calc works when only passed a single value - that for Date2.  I almost wish I could save a property of Date2.[Date Value].CurrentMember to a variable and re-use that in the Date1 range instead of Date1.[Date Value].currentmember.